# How to debug Linux PAM module?

Tags: linux, pam

I need to write PAM module for Linux. Is it pretty way to debug it without the rebooting system each time when I need to test it? What happens if the unit will not operate properly and let in? How do I turn it off? What happens if the module loading failed, for example, cause of missing dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: You can try to modify less susceptible file inside pam.d to test your modules. For example- change the pam configuration for the 'sudo' inside /etc/pam.d/   and then add your modules to perform the test. For example: In the following configuration, the 'sudo' file is modified to check the working of 'pam_auth.so' file.

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
#@include common-auth #this line is commented to make it use my pam module
auth       required   pam_auth.so
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

It is tested by using sudo command in the terminal as follows:

```
username@computer:~$ sudo nautilus
```

Kindly, put the '.so' file in the path /lib/security/. If security directory is not present, create a new directory with the same name.

Method 2: You may use dedicated tool (like [pam-tester](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pamtester/files/) to test your PAM Modules.

Answer (score 2):

Many PAM modules has `debug` option which use syslog. There are more logging in /var/log/secure .
Most of configuration you can test by using the services. For example if you have in /etc/pam.d/su the line:
`account required pam_time.so debug` 
you can test it by running `su` and check what happen.
If you have PAM configuration on services which you need to reboot in order to test then(like `login`), I recommend using Virtual Machine to fully test your PAM configuration before deploying it. You can also reboot to runlevel 1 and revert the changes it the /etc/pam.d files.

Answer (score 0):

better to refer to the OS man page for the module is being used.
For example Debian

#### [man pam_exec](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libpam-modules/pam_exec.8.en.html)

```
NAME
pam_exec - PAM module which calls an external command

SYNOPSIS
pam_exec.so [debug] [expose_authtok] [seteuid] [quiet] [stdout] [log=file] [type=type] command [...]
```

#### sample

```
session optional pam_exec.so debug log=/var/log/debug seteuid ...
```